# Transition from Finance to Applied mathematics

Tags: mathematics, masters, economics

Currently studying a Bsc in Accounting & Finance. During my studies if found an increased interest on subject such as Stochastic calculus, measure theory and mathematical analysis. I want to pursue a Msc in Applied Mathematics but wondering whether the transition is possible.

I would be pleased if someone could provide me certain similar cases/experiences or some advice with reference to study material.

Comment: Look at the entry requirements for the Msc in Applied Mathematics

Comment: For the programs that I checked, there is the general statement: Students accepted for admission should have a similar background on a related field

Comment: I searched: MSc "applied mathematics" "entry requirements". Early hits included [JKUAT](http://www.jkuat.ac.ke/departments/pam/msc-applied-mathematics/) and [Imperial College London](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/study/pg/mathematics/applied-mathematics/), who require "a Bachelors degree with at least Upper Second Class Honours, having studied Mathematics as a single subject or as a major of two subjects" and "a 2.1 degree in mathematics, applied mathematics, engineering or physics." So your degree wouldn't suffice at those institutes, at least not without negotiation. Other institutes may vary..

Comment: ...you just need to find an institute that suits you. I'm confident you will.

Answer (score 1):

As with any application, you need to make your case. But if you have studied those three math subjects and have a good understanding of them, I think you have a basis. It might be especially possible if your future studies apply math to the financial realm, of course.

It would be harder to get into a program with admissions systems that mostly check boxes of requirements rather than looking at individuals. If the admissions process gives you access to professors and potential advisors it would be easier, provided that you can convince someone that you can manage the early courses that might be required.

Answer (score 0):

I would caution you that math programs can be very different from finance.  Way higher math content, and less applied (more proofs, less use, even in applied math).

You likely need both more math prerequisites and (crucially) MUCH more math ABILITY in math program than in finance.  Just think very carefully if you have the math chops to succeed.  In any case, look very carefully at what you are getting into.  It is not just the difficulty but the abstraction.

Buffy is right to tell you to look carefully at programs and find the one that fits you.  If you go to an applied math program, you probably want one with a finance twist or at least more applied-ish and less math-ish.  Similarly, I would consider subset of finance programs that are more mathematical (real options, etc.)